# Delphi XE2 64-bit extremely slow runtime performance on string routines

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

I'm porting some applications from 32 to 64 bits delphi, which do a lot of text processing, and noticed an extreme change in processing speed. Did some tests with a few procedures, for example, this takes already more than 200% the time in 64bits than compiling to 32 (2000+ ms compared to ~900)

Is this normal?

```
function IsStrANumber(const S: AnsiString): Boolean;
var P: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := False;
  P := PAnsiChar(S);
  while P^ <> #0 do begin
    if not (P^ in ['0'..'9']) then Exit;
    Inc(P);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Const x = '1234567890';
Var a,y,z: Integer;
begin
  z := GetTickCount;
  for a := 1 to 99999999 do begin
   if IsStrANumber(x) then y := 0;//StrToInt(x);
  end;
  Caption := IntToStr(GetTickCount-z);
end;
```

Comment: Do you see the same issue if you use `StrToInt(x)` ?

Comment: Did you do some other tests that don't involve low-level pointer manipulation?

Comment: Yeah, doing only StrToInt in the loop: 2246ms vs 1498ms (64/32). Other than that, a large application I ported has a benchmark to test processing speed (it passes some text through a very long process with hundreds of string manipulation subroutines), the 64bit one takes almost twice the time to process.

Comment: I'd say do a few tests specifically casting your variables to either in64 or longint.

Comment: Int64/NativeInt still don't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test `p^ in ['0'..'9']` is slow in 64-bit.

Added an inlined function with a test for lower/upper boundary instead of the `in []` test, plus a test for an empty string.

```
function IsStrANumber(const S: AnsiString): Boolean; inline;
var
  P: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := False;
  P := Pointer(S);
  if (P = nil) then
    Exit;
  while P^ <> #0 do begin
    if (P^ < '0') then Exit;
    if (P^ > '9') then Exit;
    Inc(P);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Benchmark results:

```
        x32     x64
--------------------
hikari  1420    3963
LU RD   1029    1060
```

In 32 bit, main speed difference is inlining and that `P := PAnsiChar(S);` will call an external RTL routine for a nil check before assigning the pointer value, while `P := Pointer(S);` just assigns the pointer.

Observing that the goal here is to test if a string is a number and then convert it,
why not use the RTL [`TryStrToInt()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt), which does all in one step and handles signs,blanks as well.

Often when profiling and optimizing routines, the most important thing is to find the right approach to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. TryStrToint seems around 8 times slower than the other methods.

Comment: Topicstarter only needs to check against digits and StrToInt converts string what always will be slower. Moreover on large set of false results Try* routines are slower even more because of raising exceptions.

Comment: @Fr0sT, the Try* routines are not raising exceptions. The hit/miss factor here is determing the best outcome of calling IsStrANumber plus IntToStr vs calling just TryStrToInt. The latter is about twice as fast if all are numbers and 20 % slower in worst case scenario. It is a bit unclear if the goal here is just to check if the string is a number or actually converting the string to a number. Anyway the proposed version of IsStrANumber seems to satisfy the OP.

Comment: Yep, sure, I was confused by the "Try" prefix

Answer (score 35):

There is no current solution for this, as it is caused by the fact that the code for most of the string routines in 64 bit is compiled with `PUREPASCAL` defined, IOW, it is plain Delphi, no assembler, while the code for many of the important string routines in 32 bit was done by the FastCode project, and in assembler.

Currently, there are no FastCode equivalents in 64 bit, and I assume that the developer team will try to eliminate assembler anyway, especially since they are moving to more platforms.

This means that optimization of the generated code becomes more and more important. I hope that the announced move to an LLVM backend will speed up much of the code considerably, so pure Delphi code is not such a problem anymore.

So sorry, no solution, but perhaps an explanation.

### Update

As of XE4, quite a few FastCode routines have replaced the unoptimized routines I talk about in the above paragraphs. They are usually still `PUREPASCAL`, but yet they represent a good optimization. So the situation is not as bad as it used to be. The `TStringHelper` and plain string routines still display some bugs and some extremely slow code in **OS X** (especially where conversion from Unicode to Ansi or vice versa is concerned), but the **Win64** part of the RTL seems to be a lot better.

Comment: I see.. well that's sad. I put a lot of time into my projects into benchmarking and trying different approaches for every little routine to achieve better speed; this 64-bit thing was a big slap from Delphi, when I was expecting even a little faster code.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what specific routines are slower related to the above code.  Am I correct that it looks like there are a lot of Unicode to ANSI conversions going on?  I haven't seen a difference in performance between 32bit and 64bit binaries with my real world applications, but perhaps they don't hit the routines that are purepascaled as much.

Comment: @hikari: Benchmarking is good, if it is done on the entire project and optimizing is only useful if profilng turrns out that certain routines really need a speed up. Knuth already warned about premature optimization.

Comment: Pos() f.e seems specially affected by this.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The original Pos in XE and below is fast 32 assembler by FastCode, the PUREPASCAL Pos is plain Delphi and not done very efficiently anyway, IMO.

Comment: Maybe we could have a new `Fastcode64` project in the community.

Comment: I'd be very interested in a more optimized pure pascal version of POS(), if it made much difference.  I took a look at it but didn't see an obvious way to improve it.  However I don't see that the posted code uses library routines beyond the string type conversions.

Comment: I have seen a few comments on the FastCode mailing list that there is a provisory 64 bit assembler version of the FastCode Pos function. I guess they will also take a look at other functions. I might even help them myself, although these people know a lot of tricks I don't know.

Comment: A simple Pos(a,b) with ansistrings seems already 4-5 times slower.

Comment: and here i thought the "native CPU" compiler was so superior to any other technologies out there that it should be able to create near perfectly-performing code even from the "PUREPASCAL" implementation ;)

Comment: Oh dear, picking on "native code" once again? The 64 bit compiler is fine, but the runtime can't, of course, compete with the fastest, highly hand-optimized FastCode routines. And the culprit is the current form of the runtime, not the compiler. The 32 bit "native CPU" runtime already has these FastCode routines. IOW, this is an issue between highly optimized 32 bit code and non-optimized 64 bit code, not between "native" and "managed".

Comment: I just did a comparison in XE4 x32 mode with FastCode purepascal `PosEx_Sha_Pas_2` and `System.Pos`. To my surprise the purepascal version was faster with Unicode strings. In x64 mode, the `PosEx_Sha_Pas_2` is almost as fast as in x32 mode.

Comment: A few months ago, I did similar tests with the same FastCode PurePascal routine, both with AnsiString and with UnicodeString, but on my system it was not as fast as System.Pos, in Win32. It was almost as fast, though. In Win64, System.Pos was more or less equally fast. There was also no big difference between AnsiString and UnicodeString routines - in Windows.

Comment: @rudy i don't know how you do you test, but in Win64 System.Pos is 2x (unicode) and 5x (ansiString) more slow than in Win32 !

Comment: @loki: That may be, because that function is not in assembler, under WIN64. I did not measure such big differences.

Comment: @rudy: the only think that is true is that There was also no big difference between AnsiString and UnicodeString routines (except 2x more memory consumption). else their is a huge difference between win32 string/ansistring function and win64 string/ansiString function. this make the win64 compiler useless for web server app (who work mainly on string)

Comment: @loki: Did a quick test. Generated a 500 million length Unicodestring (called Haystack). Took the last 10 characters as Needle and searched with Pos(Needle, Haystack). Took 495 ms in Win32, 727 ms in Win64. Not such a huge difference. And both are performant enough. So stop spreading such blatant falsehoods.

Comment: @Rudy: and me i did also a quick test, with different pattern in account. And with win32 it's took 856 ms, with win64 took me 4688 ms !!! The exe demo is here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALStringBenchmark
so maybe it's you who must stop to to spread disinformation ;)

Comment: @loki: you must be talking about AnsiString. I don't care about AnsiString: it is a deprecated type. And for Unicode, it is 0.99 (Win32) vs. 1.79 (Win64) on my system. I managed to write a simple PosEx which does things in about half the time (in Win64) so that would be 0.90 seconds. It is not so easy to download your sample code as a zip, so I won't test yours, I just ran your exes.

Comment: @rudy, in your little world maybe it's deprecated !! in the real world it's so much deprecated than even emb decide to introduce it in mobile/linux under tokyo ... and all the real world, even on this stackoverflow webpage, everythink in on ansiString/Utf-8 ...

Comment: @Loki: Please change your tone, it is extremely rude. You can perhaps talk to your buddies like that, but not to me. There is no "my little world". Embarcadero added support for UTF8Strings because Linux' basic string type is UTF8. This is not the case for Win32, Win64, macOS, iOS or Android. So you'd better extend your world and get of fthe notion that UTF-8 is better than UTF-16. And since you want to code in Delphi, on these platforms, better get used to UTF-16. I agree that some of the routines for 8 byte strings are suboptiimal in 64 bit. I'll blog about a solution.

Comment: @loki: In the real world, and especially in Delphi, **AnsiString is deprecated**. You may prefer UTF-8, but the platforms that Delphi supports don't. The only exception is Linux, where the basic string type is UTF-8 (**but not Ansi**). And servers like this are generally on Linux. And of course, 8 bit stings are easier to transfer, and that is wy they are used on the Internet. That doesn't make them easier to use, just faster to transfer.. So live with UnicodeString and stop fighting it. The decision was made and they won't change it.

Comment: @rudy ?? You first say me "So stop spreading such blatant falsehoods" and now it's me that is "extremely" rude ? i guess i miss something somewhere :( to finish when something is deprecated, you have the keyword [deprecated] in delphi to say it ... strangely i don't see it in front of the ansiString declaration! Of course ansiString (ie: 8 bit string) is not deprecated! The keyword is even used more than 2760 time in the delphi tokyo source code ... I don't fight with unicode, i fight with stupidity ;) 8 bit string are everywhere, in database, in html, in text file, world is in 8 bit string

Comment: Yes, I said that because you are spreading blatant falsehoods (about.Win64 being slow -- that used to be true, it  not true anymore). That is not rude, that is simply the truth. And that AnsiString is deprecated could be derived from the fact that it is not the main string type anymore, and from the fact that initially, they did not even introduce it for the mobile compilers. Actually, they still didn't.. AnsiString is an old, deprecated Windows-only type and Ansi is even deprecated by MS.

Comment: Yea i know they didn't introduce it in mobile, delphi competitor like oxygen even point this terrible mistake to gain new client ;) anyway finally emb decide to finally introduce it to the mobile compilers showing that they was simply wrong at the beginning ;) and where i m false when i say " in Win64 System.Pos is 2x (unicode) and 5x (ansiString) more slow than in Win32" ... i even make you the exe demo to try it ! tss tss

Comment: @loki: No, not a terrible mistake. Strategy, and IMO a good one. But see [this blog post of mine](http://rvelthuis.blogspot.de/2018/01/strings-on-other-platforms-than-32-bit.html).

Comment: @rudy thanks i will take a look at RVPosExA! but it's only one string function, their is many other string function, not only pos that need to be optimized. And you understand well when you say that ansiString is still very usefull because their is nothing around Tbytes (no pos, no replace, etc..)

Comment: @loki: take a look at LU RD's blog comment. He gives a link to really fast functions, not just Pos(Ex). The PUREPASCAL implementations of FastCode are very fast too. I just made that to show that things can be improved. I am not a real fastcoder.

Comment: @rudy: RVPosExA look very promising, it's you who implement it ? i don't find implementation of other function than pos(EX) in the link of LU RD :(

Comment: @Loki: I wrote it, yes. Hence the RV in front. <g> In the QP link there is a fast implementation: `PosEx_Sha_Pas_2`. That is from the FastCode project. But he also links to an SO answer which contains a link to FastCode, which has this: http://fastcode.sourceforge.net/challenge_content/PosEX.html

Answer (score 6):

Try to avoid any string allocation in your loop.

In your case, the stack preparation of the x64 calling convention could be involved. Did you try to make `IsStrANumber` declared as `inline`?

I guess this will make it faster.

```
function IsStrANumber(P: PAnsiChar): Boolean; inline;
begin
  Result := False;
  if P=nil then exit;
  while P^ <> #0 do
    if not (P^ in ['0'..'9']) then 
      Exit else
      Inc(P);
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Const x = '1234567890';
Var a,y,z: Integer;
    s: AnsiString;
begin
  z := GetTickCount;
  s := x;
  for a := 1 to 99999999 do begin
   if IsStrANumber(pointer(s)) then y := 0;//StrToInt(x);
  end;
  Caption := IntToStr(GetTickCount-z);
end;
```

The "pure pascal" version of the RTL is indeed the cause of slowness here...

Note that it is even worse with FPC 64 bit compiler, when compared to the 32 bit version... Sounded that the Delphi compiler is not the only one! 64 bit does not mean "faster", whatever marketing says! It is sometimes even the contrary (e.g. the JRE is known to be slower on 64 bit, and a new [x32 model](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) is to be introduced in Linux when it comes about pointer size).

Comment: Inline does give a few extra ms, but it still takes almost twice the time in 64bit. Sure 64bit doesn't mean it's gonna be automaticall faster, however.. being half as fast is a big deal, when you have to wait 10 minutes to process a large text file rather than 5, etc..

Comment: Did you try my exact version? Just adding `inline` is not enough. You'll have to get rid of the whole string<->ansistring conversion, and so on. Using the temporary `s` variable and `pointer(s)` should make it faster.

Comment: Yeah your code is a bit faster, though the constant used in my example was just to show the code, in my program it's all variables. Nonetheless, compiled to 64-bit is still extremelly slower, 2-3x.

Answer (score 5):

The code can be written like this with good perfomance results:

```
function IsStrANumber(const S: AnsiString): Boolean; inline;
var
  P: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := False;
  P := PAnsiChar(S);
  while True do
  begin
    case PByte(P)^ of
      0: Break;
      $30..$39: Inc(P);
    else
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU T5600 @ 1.83GHz

- x32-bit : 2730 ms
- x64-bit : 3260 ms

Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.40GHz

- x32-bit : 2979 ms
- x64-bit : 1794 ms

Unwinding the above loop can result to faster execution:

```
function IsStrANumber(const S: AnsiString): Boolean; inline; 
type
  TStrData = packed record
    A: Byte;
    B: Byte;
    C: Byte;
    D: Byte;
    E: Byte;
    F: Byte;
    G: Byte;
    H: Byte;
  end;
  PStrData = ^TStrData;
var
  P: PStrData;
begin
  Result := False;
  P := PStrData(PAnsiChar(S));
  while True do
  begin
    case P^.A of
      0: Break;
      $30..$39:
        case P^.B of
          0: Break;
          $30..$39:
            case P^.C of
              0: Break;
              $30..$39:
                case P^.D of
                  0: Break;
                  $30..$39:
                    case P^.E of
                      0: Break;
                      $30..$39:
                        case P^.F of
                          0: Break;
                          $30..$39:
                            case P^.G of
                              0: Break;
                              $30..$39:
                                case P^.H of
                                  0: Break;
                                  $30..$39: Inc(P);
                                else
                                  Exit;
                                end;
                            else
                              Exit;
                            end;
                        else
                          Exit;
                        end;
                    else
                      Exit;
                    end;
                else
                  Exit;
                end;
            else
              Exit;
            end;
        else
          Exit;
        end;
    else
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU T5600 @ 1.83GHz

- x32-bit : 2199 ms
- x64-bit : 1934 ms

Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.40GHz

- x32-bit : 1170 ms
- x64-bit : 1279 ms

If you also apply what Arnaud Bouchez said you can make it even faster.

Comment: This one is a bit odd: removing the 0 case for more speed (and the nil check in previous): 32bit: 811 vs 656, 64bit: 1108 vs 1654. So, in 32 bit this example is slower, but in 64bit it's faster oO

Comment: Keeping the 0 check for safety: 32bit: 1607ms, 64bit 1060

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of 64-bit is in address space, not speed (unless your code is limited by addressable memory).

Historically, this sort of character manipulation code has always been slower on wider machines.  It was true moving from the 16-bit 8088/8086 to the 32-bit 386.  Putting an 8-bit char in a 64-bit register is a waste of memory bandwidth & cache.

For speed, you can avoid char variables, use pointers, use lookup tables, use bit-parallelism (manipulate 8 chars in one 64-bit word), or use the SSE/SSE2... instructions.  Obviously, some of these will make your code CPUID dependent.  Also, open the CPU window while debugging, and look for the compiler doing stupid things "for" you like silent string conversions (especially around calls).

You might try looking at some of the native Pascal routines in the FastCode Library.  E.G. PosEx_Sha_Pas_2, while not as fast as the assembler versions, is faster than the RTL code (in 32-bits).

Comment: PosEx_Sha_Pas_2 seems actually ~60-70% slower than Pos in 64-bit (and 10x slower in 32bit).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two functions. One checks only for positive numbers. The second checks for negative aswell. And is not limited to size. The second one is 4x faster than regular `Val`.

```
function IsInteger1(const S: String): Boolean; overload;
var
  E: Integer;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Val(S, Value, E);
  Result := E = 0;
end;


function IsInteger2(const S: String): Boolean; inline; 
var
    I: Integer;
begin
    Result := False;
    I := 0;
  while True do
  begin
    case Ord(S[I+1]) of
      0: Break;
      $30..$39:
        case Ord(S[I+2]) of
          0: Break;
          $30..$39:
            case Ord(S[I+3]) of
              0: Break;
              $30..$39:
                case Ord(S[I+4]) of
                  0: Break;
                  $30..$39:
                    case Ord(S[I+5]) of
                      0: Break;
                      $30..$39:
                        case Ord(S[I+6]) of
                          0: Break;
                          $30..$39:
                            case Ord(S[I+7]) of
                              0: Break;
                              $30..$39:
                                case Ord(S[I+8]) of
                                  0: Break;
                                  $30..$39:
                                    case Ord(S[I+9]) of
                                      0: Break;
                                      $30..$39: 
                                        case Ord(S[I+10]) of
                                          0: Break;
                                          $30..$39: Inc(I, 10);
                                        else
                                          Exit;
                                        end;
                                    else
                                      Exit;
                                    end;
                                else
                                  Exit;
                                end;
                            else
                              Exit;
                            end;
                        else
                          Exit;
                        end;
                    else
                      Exit;
                    end;
                else
                  Exit;
                end;
            else
              Exit;
            end;
        else
          Exit;
        end;
    else
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

function IsInteger3(const S: String): Boolean; inline;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  case Ord(S[1]) of
    $2D,
    $30 .. $39:
    begin
      I := 1;
      while True do
      case Ord(S[I + 1]) of
        0:
        Break;
        $30 .. $39:
        case Ord(S[I + 2]) of
          0:
          Break;
          $30 .. $39:
          case Ord(S[I + 3]) of
            0:
            Break;
            $30 .. $39:
            case Ord(S[I + 4]) of
              0:
              Break;
              $30 .. $39:
              case Ord(S[I + 5]) of
                0:
                Break;
                $30 .. $39:
                case Ord(S[I + 6]) of
                  0:
                  Break;
                  $30 .. $39:
                  case Ord(S[I + 7]) of
                    0:
                    Break;
                    $30 .. $39:
                    case Ord(S[I + 8]) of
                      0:
                      Break;
                      $30 .. $39:
                      case Ord(S[I + 9]) of
                        0:
                        Break;
                        $30 .. $39:
                        case Ord(S[I + 10]) of
                          0:
                          Break;
                          $30 .. $39:
                          case Ord(S[I + 11]) of
                            0:
                            Break;
                            $30 .. $39:
                            case Ord(S[I + 12]) of
                              0:
                              Break;
                              $30 .. $39:
                              case Ord(S[I + 13]) of
                                0:
                                Break;
                                $30 .. $39:
                                Inc(I, 13);
                              else
                                Exit;
                              end; 
                            else
                              Exit;
                            end; 
                          else
                            Exit;
                          end; 
                        else
                          Exit;
                        end; 
                      else
                        Exit;
                      end; 
                    else
                      Exit;
                    end; 
                  else
                    Exit;
                  end; 
                else
                  Exit;
                end; 
              else
                Exit;
              end;  
            else
              Exit;
            end;  
          else
            Exit;
          end;   
        else
          Exit;
        end;    
      else
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  else
    Exit;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest way so far, although it will freeze if you call it with an AnsiString. Thanks.

Comment: @hikari Try calling the `IsStrANumber` with `S: String` and this function. There is a string conversion with `IsStrANumber`